# What is minimum Android version can install google play service version 7.5.0 through google play store?

Tags: android, google-play-services

We need to have Google Play Services 7.5.0 (minimum) available on the Android devices for Urban Airship (Push Notifications). What is the minimum Android version that will install Google Play Services 7.5.0 through the Google Play Store?

What we know is:

Android 2.3.5 will only install Google Play Service 3.2.67 through the Google Play Store.

Android 2.3.5 will install Google Play Services 7.5.0, but it will only do it manually and NOT through the Google Play Store.

The manual approach is not a suitable approach for our clients customers.
We need to be able to have them install 7.5.0 of the Google Play Services through the Google Play store and we need the minimum Android version that will do this.

**UPDATE**

The actual problem is:

Our clients mobile phone has android version 2.3.5 installed. When they open our app (require google play service version 7.5), the system ask them to update google play service. After they click update button (update through google play store), the updated google play service version is 3.2.67. After that, when they open our app again, the system still ask them to update google play service. There is no way to skip this update.

My question is what android version is able to update google play service to version 7.5 **THROUGH GOOGLE PLAY STORE**?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: You cannot.

The expanded answer: You cannot, unless the Developer has specified this on their site. You could also email them to ask them. Which mean you cannot know what's the minimum supported API by Google Play Services app.

**WORKAROUND**

Google Play does not provide any official APIs for retrieving metadata. You could however, check the unofficial API at http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/.

Specifically, take a look at the Wiki page [HowToSearchApps](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToSearchApps). The response to the query contains version information:

```
{
  "app": [
    {
      "rating": "4.642857142857143",
      "title": "Ruboto IRB",
      "ratingsCount": 14,
      "creator": "Jan Berkel",
      "appType": "APPLICATION",
      "id": "9089465703133677000",
      "packageName": "org.jruby.ruboto.irb",
      "version": "0.1",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "creatorId": "\"Jan Berkel\"",
      "ExtendedInfo": {
        "category": "Tools",
        "permissionId": [
...
```

Comment: Thanks @cw fei. However you may not understand my question well. I know Android version 9 can use google play service 7.5 but you can not install it through google play store by clicking update google play service button in popup window in our client's mobile phone. It only allows you to install google play service 3.2.67.

Comment: I updated my question as well. Hope you can provide me a more helpful answer :)